# AngularJS the AJax data not submitting back to HTML

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, angularjs

I have two pages Index.html and default.aspx. 
From Index.html, an ajax hit will be submitted to default.aspx where it will process database request and return a json string to html page.
sample code given below.

I'm using angular **1.2.26**.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersController">

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in names">
    {{ x.id + ', ' + x.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    function customersController($scope, $http) {          
        $scope.response = $http.get("http://localhost/default.aspx")
                               .success(function(response) {

                $scope.names = response.records;
        });
    }
</script>
```

default.aspx

```
public static string GetEmployees()
{            

    // ... stuff to grab data goes here ...


    // DataRow dr;
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
        {
            row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
        }
        rows.Add(row);
    }

    rowcoln.Add("records", rows);

    string jsonData = serializer.Serialize(rowcoln);
    //  JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    con.Close();
   //sample jsondata
   jsonData = "{\"records\": [{\"id\":200321,\"name\": \"test\"}]}";
    return jsonData;

}
```

The jsonData is receiving the data but not returning back to the html page.

Comment: You have an error in your success callback. Remove the first line saying `debugger` ...

Comment: I verified the result is returning from the aspx page but not receiving in html

Comment: Yep, the execution normally stops at that point, just before `binding` response to `$scope.names`

Comment: I removed the debugger but still issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use $scope.$apply
Refer: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html
Also refer: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-$scope.$apply()

Answer (score 0):

Attach the controller with the app, Here is the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/15051/

```
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="customersController"> 
   <ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in names">
    {{ x.id + ', ' + x.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>

<Script>
     var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
     app.controller('customersController', ['$scope',
     function($scope,$hhtp) {

         $scope.names =  [
         {"id":"1", "name":"Doe"}, 
         {"id":"2", "name":"Smith"},
         {"id":"3", "name":"Jones"}
         ];   }]);
</Script>
```

Output:

1, Doe
2, Smith
3, Jones

Comment: I want to return the result from the aspx page.

Comment: $scope.names is a observable, which means any change made to the object in aspx will be update automatically to the object. So all you have to do is to send $scope.names back to the service to save.

Answer (score 0):

since im not mentioning the method the  `return jsonData;`  didnt return the expected result but `response.write(jsonData)` did the trick.

So unless otherwise not mentioning method i guess **`response.write`** will return the data fetch from the process page.